# Need help with abi decode and encode

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, javascript, encoding, decoding

the solidity data structure and code is as follows :

```
struct Order {
        bytes32 sender;
        int128 priceX18;
        int128 amount;
        uint64 expiration;
        uint64 nonce;
 }

 struct SignedOrder {
        Order order;
        bytes signature;
 }
    
struct MatchOrderAMM {
        uint32 productId;
        int128 baseDelta;
        int128 quoteDelta;
        SignedOrder taker;
}
```

and in solidity code the abi decode is done like so :

```
function processTransaction(bytes calldata transaction) internal {

        TransactionType txType = TransactionType(uint8(transaction[0]));

       if (txType == TransactionType.MatchOrderAMM) {
            MatchOrderAMM memory txn = abi.decode(
                transaction[1:],
                (MatchOrderAMM)
            );
    }
}
```

and with ethers on web 2 i do this :

```
let tx = ethers.utils.concat([
       ethers.utils.arrayify(TransactionType.MatchOrderAMM),
       ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(
         [
           {
             type: "tuple",
             name: "MatchOrderAMM",
             components: [
               {
                 type: "tuple",
                 name: "taker",
                 components: [
                   {
                     type: "tuple",
                     name: "order",
                     components: [
                       {
                         name: "sender",
                         type: "bytes32",
                       },
                       {
                         name: "amount",
                         type: "int128",
                       },
                       {
                         name: "priceX18",
                         type: "int128",
                       },
                       {
                         name: "expiration",
                         type: "uint64",
                       },
                       {
                         name: "nonce",
                         type: "uint64",
                       },
                     ],
                   },
                   {
                     name: "signature",
                     type: "bytes",
                   },
                 ],
               },
               {
                 name: "productId",
                 type: "uint32",
               },
               {
                 name: "baseDelta",
                 type: "int128",
               },
               {
                 name: "quoteDelta",
                 type: "int128",
               },
             ],
           } as any,
         ],
         [
           {
             taker: transaction.taker,
             productId: "1",
             baseDelta: transaction.baseDelta,
             quoteDelta: transaction.quoteDelta,
           },
         ]
       ),
])
```

the encoding completes with no issues but onchain/in solidity it is not decoding an error occors please help me verify if the ethers web2 encoding is dont properly. especially with the type that us defined for encoding

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid memory-consuming `abi.decode()` call, by just casting bytes to struct and enjoy gas-free decoding fields on the flight:

```
function processTransaction(bytes calldata transaction) internal {
    TransactionType txType = TransactionType(uint8(transaction[0]));
    if (txType == TransactionType.MatchOrderAMM) {
        MatchOrderAMM calldata txn;
        assembly ("memory-safe") {
            txn := transaction.offset
        }
    }
}
```

More info about this trick here: https://x.com/k06a/status/1706934230779883656